# how to get checked box based on value, and save to database

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have two database tables to manage user access:

1. Table `Level`

   ```
   lvl_Id| level_name
   1     |  admin
   2     |  user_1
   3     |  user_2
   ```
2. Table `Menu`

   ```
   Menu_name | menu_allowed
   Edit_data | +1+2+
   Print_data| +1+2+3+
   Edit_user | +1+
   Edit_index| +1+2+
   view_index| +1+2+3+
   ```

What I want to do is change `menu_allowed` in Table `menu`, with checkbox in view page and update the table.

This is my code in view page:

```php
<tr>
<td>Hak akses</td>
<td> : </td>
<td id="check"><?php foreach($test as $data) : ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="<?php echo $data->menu_allowed ?> " /> <?php echo $data->menu_nama ?> <br />
<?php endforeach; ?></td>
```

What I want get in the form:

```
User 1 :[v] Edit Data
        [v] Print Data
        [ ] Edit User
        [v] Edit Index
        [v] View Index

User 2 :[ ] Edit Data
        [v] Print Data
        [ ] Edit User
        [ ] Edit Index
        [v] View Index
```

My question is how I get the checked box (if have number in `menu_name`) and how I update the table menu. For example if user 2, I check on edit data and edit index the database will update:

```
Menu_name | menu_allowed
Edit_data | +1+2+3+
Print_data| +1+2+3+
Edit_user | +1+
Edit_index| +1+2+3+
view_index| +1+2+3+
```

Comment: normalise your database structure save your self a world of pain

Comment: @dagon normalise my database, i have 3table,table level, table menu and table relation which contains lvl_id and lvl_name so how i display the checkbox like i want?